# New Error.. Cant Figure This One Out

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

My timestamp code worked well before i put it in a function.. Get this parse error on line 55, ive marked the line number with "// LINE 55", cant figure it out :(

Here's my error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\wamp\www\flueforumdk\config.php on line 55
```

Here's the calling of the function:

```
$GET_UNIX_STAMP_FROM_DB = $art[tidspunkt];
$UNIX_TIME_SECONDS = $GET_UNIX_STAMP_FROM_DB;

echo timestamp_converter($UNIX_TIME_SECONDS);
```

Here's my function code:

```
  ## TIMESTAMP CONVERTER FUNCTION
   function timestamp_converter($UNIX_TIME_SECONDS){
      // UDREGNING FRA UNIX TIME
      $tid = time() - $UNIX_TIME_SECONDS;
      $timer = floor($tid/3600);
      $minutter = floor($tid/60);
      $dage = floor($timer / 24);
      $uge = floor($dage / 7);
      $month = floor($dage / 30.5);
      $aar = floor($dage / 365);
 if($tid < 60){
   echo"<b>$tid</b> sekunder";
 } elseif ($tid > 60){
   echo"";
   }
 if($minutter == 0){
   echo"";
 } elseif ($minutter < 60){
 if($minutter == 1){
   echo"<b>$minutter</b> minut";
 }else{
   echo"<b>$minutter</b> minutter";
 }
 }
     if($timer == 0){
        echo"";
      } elseif ($timer < 24){
     if($timer == 1){
             echo"<b>$timer</b> time";
   }else{
        echo"<b>$timer</b> timer";
   }
    }
     //LINE 55   if($dage == 0){
      echo"";
     } elseif ($dage < 7){
       if($dage == 1){
           echo"<b>$dage</b> dag";
           }else{
         echo"<b>$dage</b> dage";
         }
      }
  if($uge == 0){
  echo"";
     } elseif ($uge < 4){
      if($uge == 1){
       echo"<b>$uge</b> uge";
         }else{
           echo"<b>$uge</b> uger";
        }
       }
    if($month == 0){
        echo"";
      } elseif ($month < 12){
        if($month == 1){
         echo"<b>$month</b> måned";
         }else{
        echo"<b>$month</b> måneder";
        }
        }
        if($aar == 0){
          echo"";
           } elseif ($aar > 0){
          if($aar == 1){
               echo"<b>$aar</b> år";
                  }else{
               echo"<b>$aar</b> år";
                  }
              }
       }
```

Comment: Terribly spaced code. What's the point of `if($condition == 0){ echo ""; } else {`? Why not just `if($condition != 0) {`? That would cut your code and help with readability (you might even remove your syntax error in the process!)

Comment: other than the commented out line 55, it works for me. Are you sure that's the exact code on the server --working here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/iPLLVC

Comment: Sorry for the spaced out code dude.. Did it because it wouldnt fit in the "code sample"-box otherwise :) tried your suggestion with != in stead of == ... didnt make a diffrence :( this i seriously a mystery for me!

Comment: HOMIE... i SALUTE YOU!!! IT WORKED!! Been working on this for aged, you saved my life :D :D :D